# Fail to implement pattern_capture token filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement an Elasticsearch pattern_capture filter which can turn EDR-00004 into the tokens: [EDR-00004, 00004, 4]. I am (still) working with Elasticsearch 2.4, but there is no difference with the documentation to the current ES version.

I have followed the example in the documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html

This are my tests and results:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test_index' -d '{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "process_number_filter": {
                    "type": "pattern_capture",
                    "preserve_original": 1,
                    "patterns": [
                        "([A-Za-z]+-([0]+([0-9]+)))"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "process_number_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "pattern",
                    "filter": ["process_number_filter"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'

curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test_index/_analyze' -d '
{
  "analyzer": "process_number_analyzer",
  "text": "EDR-00002"
}'

curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test_index/_analyze' -d '
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "tokenizer": "standard",
  "filter": ["process_number_filter"],
  "text": "EDR-00002"
}'
```

Returns:

```
{"acknowledged":true}

{
    "tokens": [{
        "token": "EDR",
        "start_offset": 0,
        "end_offset": 3,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 0
    }, {
        "token": "00002",
        "start_offset": 4,
        "end_offset": 9,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 1
    }]
}

{
    "tokens": [{
        "token": "edr",
        "start_offset": 0,
        "end_offset": 3,
        "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position": 0
    }, {
        "token": "00002",
        "start_offset": 4,
        "end_offset": 9,
        "type": "<NUM>",
        "position": 1
    }]
}
```

I understand that

1. I don't have to group the whole regex, as I have preserve_original set
2. I can replace stuff with \d and/or \w, but this way I don't have to think about escaping.

Also made sure my regex is right.

```
>>> m = re.match(r"([A-Za-z]+-([0]+([0-9]+)))", "EDR-00004")                                                                                                                                                                                
>>> m.groups()
('EDR-00004', '00004', '4')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but I found the answer and maybe it could help people in the future.

My problem was the default tokenizer, which would split the text before passing it into my filter. By adding my own tokenizer, which overwrites the default splitter `"\W+"` into `"[^\\w-]+"`, my filter received the whole word, and thus created the right tokens.

This is now my custom setting:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test_index' -d '{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "process_number_filter": {
                    "type": "pattern_capture",
                    "preserve_original": 1,
                    "patterns": [
                        "([A-Za-z]+-([0]+([0-9]+)))"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "process_number_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "pattern",
                    "pattern": "[^\\w-]+"
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "process_number_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "process_number_tokenizer",
                    "filter": ["process_number_filter"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Which lead to the following result:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "EDR-00002",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "00002",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "2",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```